# Unable to get access of css file trough html

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, svelte

I'm trying to access main.css from app.html in order to make Tailwind CSS work because if I put it in style brackets in .svelte file its self then it just gives me an error, dose any one know why

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./routes/main.css">
```

doesn't work?

HTML in which I'm trying to access CSS

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.png" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./routes/main.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  %svelte.head%
</head>
```

CSS file if it has to do anything with it

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
    .nav-btn {
        @apply font-medium
        dark:hover:bg-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-800
        hover:text-white dark:hover:text-black
        rounded-lg transition-colors duration-300
        px-3 py-1;
    }
}

.h1{
    color: aqua;
}
```

[image: folder structure]

Comment: `href="./routes/main.css"` the issue is probably the `.` use an absolute path starting with `/` from your documentroot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only files inside `static` can be referenced inside your `app.html`. If you move the file there, it can be found.
However, in your case, this might not work since the CSS file is not final (TailwindCSS likely needs to process it first), and stuff inside `static` is, well, static. To solve your specific problem, import the css file inside the script tag of your `index.svelte` or main `__layout.svelte`:

```html
<script>
  import './path/to/your/main.css';
</script>
```

This article gives a good overview of how to setup TailwindCSS and SvelteKit: https://codechips.me/tailwindcss-sveltekit-the-easy-way/